# How to specificy preconfigured webshpere-liberty SSLSocketFactory to Netty rective client used by spring-webclient

Tags: websphere-liberty, reactor-netty, spring-webclient

I am building a spring boot application that runs on #websphere-liberty profile. I am using a Spring webclient for outbound connections. All good except that I am not able to specify liberty SSL context to the netty httpclient used by Spring Webclient.

Any help on how how to specify pre-configured libery ssl context to Netty httpclient is greatly appreciated.

**IBM documentation says that I should use SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() to get liberty SSL context. But I don't see any way to pass this to Netty HttpClient.**

Ref: [https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ssl.html]

This is what I tried, but it is not pointing to the SSL context configured by #Websphere-liberty. Instead, it seems to create a new one. Because of that, the trust/keystores are not available to the netty HttpClient and I get an error saying that the peer is not trusted.

```
@Bean
public WebClient createWebClient() throws SSLException {
    JdkSslContext jdkSslContext = new 
    JdkSslContext(SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"),true,
                null, IdentityCipherSuiteFilter.INSTANCE,null,ClientAuth.NONE,
                null,false);
    ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = HttpClient.create().secure { t -> t.sslContext(jdkSslContext) }
    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).build();
}
```

Comment: I have not used Netty and really don't know anything about it.  But I'm curious if you don't call JdkSslContext will the call to HttpClient.create.secure() just pick up with is set as the default?   If it does then it seem it may pick up Liberty's default.  If your Liberty configuration uses multiple SSL configurations then outbound filters can be used to select the correct SSL configuration for the outbound call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Alaine. I tried the option but it doesn't pickup the liberty ssl context.

Comment: Can anyone from #reactor-netty help on this?